# How do i insert data from my dropdown list in unity to my database?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a countries drop down list in Unity so that when they select a country and click the submit button, it will be stored in the database. I have no clue as to how i will be able to pull this off due to the fact this is my first time using unity and trying to incorporate the use of a database into a mobile app, although i have managed to insert data such as username and email into my database through an input field,i do not know how to insert data when the information comes from a drop down list. Some tips and tricks would be very appreciated!

Comment: Send the `captionText` from the dropdown object. So when the submit button is clicked, take the captionText and send it the way you sent the other queries.

Comment: sorry i'm still really new to unity, how do i go about getting this captionText?

Comment: So the first thing you want to do is get a reference to the dropdown object. If your dropdown is tagged `dropdown`, we can do `GameObject.FindWithTag("dropdown").GetComponent(typeof(Dropdown)) as Dropdown`, then when the `Submit` button is pressed, we can do `dropdown.captionText` to access the selected option. There might be some syntactical errors here because I'm on mobile and cant verify but hopefully this should be enough to get you going